# NVDA reading only last loaded the content of div and skipping remaining

Tags: angular, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

I have an 3 different div dynamically loading based on search criteria. Each div I have added **"role='alert'", "tabindex='0'" and "aria-live='polite'"**. I have noticed DOM was loading immediately all 3 div but NVDA speaker reading only last loaded div content. I have verified in NVDA speak viewer all 3 div content displaying here but while reading it's speaking last content.

Once I click on the button. NVDA speaks line by line all content.

I am using Angular 5. Please find the below code for more information.

HTML template:

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" tabindex="0" (click)="getWatsonDetails()"/>
<div *ngIf="isHiddenData">
  <div id="main{{i}}" tabindex="-1" class="chat" *ngFor="let passage of watsonResponse;let i=index;">
    <p role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" tabindex="0" style="font-size: medium; margin-bottom: 4px;">
      {{passage.value.input.text}}
    </p>
    <div role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" tabindex="-1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" *ngIf="passage.who==='watson'&& passage.label==='DL codes'">
      <span class="btn-group-star" *ngFor="let item of passage.value.codesWithLinks; let pwe=index">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary wlDlBtn" tabindex="0" id="pdfbtn{{i}}{{pwe}}" *ngIf="item.type==='pdf'" type="button"
                placement="top-left" attr.aria-label="{{'Document '+item.code}}">
          <span>{{'Document - '+item.code}}</span>
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary wlDlBtn" tabindex="0" id="wblbtn{{i}}{{pwe}}" *ngIf="item.type==='weblink'" type="button"
                placement="top-left" attr.aria-label="{{'Document '+item.code}} ">
          <span role="link">{{'Web Link - '+item.code}}</span>
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary wlDlBtn" tabindex="0" id="excelbtn{{i}}{{pwe}}" *ngIf="item.type==='excel'" type="button"
                placement="top-left" attr.aria-label="{{'Document '+item.code}} ">
          <span>{{'Document - '+item.code}}</span>
        </button>
        <br>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" style="font-size: medium; margin-bottom: 4px;" *ngIf="passage.who==='watson' && passage.label==='Relevance node'">
      <p role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" tabindex="0"> {{passage.value.input.text}} </p> <br />
      <div role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="display:flex;margin-top: 1em;">
        <div id="drop_{{i}}">
          <button role="checkbox" tabindex="0" id="feedbackDropBtn_{{i}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="select" class="drop-toggle btn flat">
            <span aria-hidden="true">Select</span>
            <span id="feedbackDropBtn" aria-hidden="true">Select</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div id="feedback_{{i}}" class="drop-show" *ngIf="!passage.isDisabled" style="height: 85px;margin-left: 3%;overflow-y: scroll;">
            <label id="check{{cb}}" *ngFor="let option of optionsArray;let cb=index">
              <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem_{{i}}{{cb}}" attr.aria-labelledby="{{'chkbx' + cb}}" name="checkbox" tabindex="0" />
              <span id="chkbx{{cb}}">{{option.code}}</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
          <button type="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Submit" style="text-align: center;height: 2.2em;margin-left: 0.5em;" class="submitbtn" id="submit_{{i}}">
            <span style="color:#4E8416">Submit</span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript code:

```ts
watsonResponse: any = [{ "label": "text", "value": { "input": { "text": "Here are the documents or links that I found that match most closely to your search criteria. Click on a link to view the document in the Document Viewer. If the link is for a webpage, the link will be opened in a new tab in your browser." } }, "who": "watson", "time": "2021-9-3|9:39:29" }, { "label": "DL codes", "value": { "input": { "text": "AB0003,AB0037" }, "codesWithLinks": [{ "code": "AB0003", "link": "", "summary": "Cultural Competency Training 2021", "type": "pdf", "DLWL_links_int": "", "checked": false }, { "code": "AB0037", "link": "", "summary": "Cultural Competency Training 2020", "type": "pdf", "DLWL_links_int": "", "checked": false }, { "code": "None", "checked": false }] }, "who": "watson", "time": "2021-9-3|9:39:29" }, { "label": "Relevance node", "value": { "input": { "text": "Were you able to find what you were looking for?  Please help us continue to improve your experience by selecting the document in the drop-down menu that best helped you and clicking submit for a thumbs-up.  If you did not find what you were looking for, please select “None” from the drop-down and click submit for a thumbs-down to continue." } }, "who": "watson", "time": "2021-9-3|9:39:29" }]

  optionsArray: any = [{ "code": "Dot net" }, { "code": "Java" }, { "code": "Python" }];
  isHiddenData: boolean = false;

  getWatsonDetails() {
    this.isHiddenData = true;
  }
```

Note: In real-time data render through service and also ignore CSS. [Click here to see, NVDA speak viewer displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWB02.png)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in this question?

Comment: Context is important, can you post your html here and also give us an indication of what the AOM - Accessibility Object Model says for these added divs. I would venture to guess the AOM, which is what the screenreader actually reads, isn't receiving the div information.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I have added my code. NVDA speak viewer displaying all the content but while it come speaks it's reading only 1 section and also I have tried to timeout to render the content every 5min. still not working as expected. Please advice

Comment: are you updating your angular bindings with of or in?

Comment: @NathanielFlick angular binding with of (Eg: *ngFor="let passage of watsonResponse;let i=index;")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely because you are using `role=“alert”` on those divs. Using that role is equivalent to using `aria-live=“assertive”` which may override messages queued up for the screen reader.

Per the comment from @slugolicious, the definition of aria-live (w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) says that "User agents or assistive technologies MAY choose to clear queued changes when an assertive change occurs." That is, multiple role="alert" or aria-live="assertive" elements might clear the message from other elements so that might be the cause of the problem.

Per the comments, having `aria-live` and `aria-atomic` set on both the `<p>` tag as well as the `<div>` tag for each alert may be causing some content to be parsed and read off twice once the initial queuing issue is resolved. As stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions#additional_live_region_attributes: "The aria-atomic=BOOLEAN is used to set whether or not the screen reader should always present the live region as a whole." Setting these attributes twice around the content of each alert may be causing some content to be queued up to be read off by the screen reader twice.

I'd suggest wrapping the `<p>` and `<div>` tags in an outer element that has `aria-live="polite"` and `aria-atomic="true"` declared just once around the entire content of each alert.

Something like:

```
<div id="alertWrapper1" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"
    <p tabindex="-1" style="font-size: medium; margin-bottom: 4px;">
      {{passage.value.input.text}}
    </p>
    <div tabindex="-1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" *ngIf="passage.who==='watson'&& passage.label==='DL codes'">
      <span class="btn-group-star" *ngFor="let item of passage.value.codesWithLinks; let pwe=index">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary wlDlBtn" tabindex="0" id="pdfbtn{{i}}{{pwe}}" *ngIf="item.type==='pdf'" type="button"
                placement="top-left" attr.aria-label="{{'Document '+item.code}}">
          <span>{{'Document - '+item.code}}</span>
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary wlDlBtn" tabindex="0" id="wblbtn{{i}}{{pwe}}" *ngIf="item.type==='weblink'" type="button"
                placement="top-left" attr.aria-label="{{'Document '+item.code}} ">
          <span role="link">{{'Web Link - '+item.code}}</span>
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary wlDlBtn" tabindex="0" id="excelbtn{{i}}{{pwe}}" *ngIf="item.type==='excel'" type="button"
                placement="top-left" attr.aria-label="{{'Document '+item.code}} ">
          <span>{{'Document - '+item.code}}</span>
        </button>
        <br>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, something else I noticed: you have `tabindex="0"` set on a native `<p>` tag. Per https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2021-01-28-how-to-use-the-tabindex-attribute/: "There is a myth that applying tabindex="0" to non-interactive elements (paragraphs, headings, lists, etc.) helps “improve” accessibility by providing a way for a person who uses a screen reader to focus on all the content present in a webpage or web app. Unfortunately, this well-intentioned idea actually does not create a good assistive technology experience."

As a best practice, I would advise you to avoid using `tabindex="0"` on non-interactive content. Every screen reader I have experience with allows for users to scan through and access non-interactive, text content on a webpage without the requiring the use of the `tabindex` attribute.

Comment: Can you add a reference to your answer?  Point to the definition of `aria-live` (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) and note that it says *"User agents or assistive technologies **MAY** choose to clear queued changes when an assertive change occurs."*  That is, multiple `role="alert"` or `aria-live="assertive"` elements *might* clear the message from other elements so that *might* be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I will update this answer and include references from now on. My apologies, @slugolicious. Thank you for the pointers!

Comment: @GarretPatten Thank you for your feedback. If remove role="alert" or aria-live="assertive" from each element and add it to parent div element, it was reading twice so I have added to each element and also I have tried removing role="alert" or aria-live="assertive" entire application NVDA is not reading anything. Can you suggest alternative of these.

Comment: Of course, @Dinesh! I think it may have something to do with declaring `aria-live` and `aria-atomic` around related parts of the alert each time. See my updated answer!

Comment: @GarretPatten thank you very much for your time. Now I got it, why it was reading twice.

Comment: @GarretPatten First time click working expected but second time click. it will bind some more data dynamic to same list so that time it start reading from beginning. Is it work like that or how to read only second time push??

Comment: @Dinesh You're welcome! And, if aria-live and aria-atomic are used on a container, all the contents of that container will be read off. If you'd like additional information that appears to be read off, it will have to be in a separate container with aria-live and aria-atomic tags.

Comment: @GarretPatten Thank you once again. It's working fine.